# @Html.DropDownListFor Item default nos primeiros valores da lista

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Boa tarde, senhores.

Eu utilizo `DropDownListFor` para carregar listas, exemplo carregar todos os meus clientes para ser selecionado. Contudo, eu preciso que se não aparecer um registro na listagem tenha a opção de add um novo item.

Eu conseguir escrever o código, contudo o problema é que o item para add um novo registro fica no final da minha lista, gostaria que ele seja o segundo item.
O primeiro item é o selecionar, segundo novo e os demais os que estão cadastrados.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClienteId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Clientes, "Id", "Nome") ,"Selecione")
```

JS:

```
 $('#ClienteId').append($('<option>', { text: "Novo", value: 0, selected: false }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo assim:

```
$('#ClienteId').append($('<option>', { text: "Novo", value: 0, selected: false }));
var options = $('#ClienteId option');
$(options[options.size() - 1]).insertAfter($(options)[1]));
```

Comment: O comando insertAfter não foi reconhecido, pra min.

Comment: Eu dei uma atualizada na resposta. Chegou a ver?

Comment: Opa, não tinha visto. Então, testei código e não ocorreu erro, contudo não funcionou. O item "Novo"  ficou na última posição

Comment: Acho que agora vai aparecer. Acabei de testar aqui numa tela minha. A primeira versão estava com erro realmente.

Comment: Então pra min não funcionou. A ordem apresentada é a ordem que os dados foram inseridos.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais nada, eu não acho que essa maneira ideal de especificar que um novo registro será inserido, a *DropDownList* deveria ter apenas os itens que podem ser utilizados para preencher o campo no *model* e o aquele campo opcional que é exibido quando nenhum item está selecionado.

Você poderia por exemplo ter uma *checkbox* que quando marcada habilitaria o *DropDownList* e quando desmarcada exibiria alguma outra opção adicionar um novo cliente.

Mas emfim, você pode fazer a inserção desse campo "Novo" na *DropDownList* pelo lado do servidor da seguinte maneira:

(Para aqueles que irão me julgar, eu sei que é uma solução feia, mas não há nada além disso que possa ser feito para responder a pergunta do OP pelo lado do servidor).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Vamos supor que os dados dos clientes vieram do banco de dados
    var clientes = new List<Cliente>
    {
        new Cliente { Id = 1, Nome = "Foo" },
        new Cliente { Id = 2, Nome = "Bar" }
    };

    // Com a coleção de Clientes em mãos, insira um novo Cliente no primeiro índice e atribua "Novo" à propriedade que será exibida na DropDownList
    clientes.Insert(0, new Cliente { Nome = "Novo" });

    // E agora transforme a coleção de Clientes em uma SelectList
    ViewBag.Clientes = new SelectList(clientes, "Id", "Nome");

    return View();
}
```

Comment: E o que seria uma boa solução, falando em usabilidade? Vejo alguns sistemas que estão alta trabalhando dessa forma e eu gostei também da usabilidade dele.

Comment: @Zica O que o sistema que você está trabalhando faz nesse caso? Quando o usuário seleciona a opção "Novo"?

Comment: Ela abre um form dentro do dialog modal para cadastrar um novo cliente. Após salvar o novo cliente automaticamente é atualizado o DropDownListFor e selecionado  o cliente cadastrado. Isso tudo já está funcionando, só queria melhorar.

Comment: Eu faria da seguinte forma, exibiria o DropDownList apenas com os clientes, e do lado dele um botão para adicionar um novo cliente e colocaria o dialog modal para abrir quando ocorresse um click nesse botão